# Returning a PHP array via AJAX working without json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Just a little quirk I've come accross and I think I must be missing something so would like some clarification to further my understanding of what's going on with my code.

I post a form via jQuery AJAX, the form is processed by PHP and in the PHP I have the line

```
return $status;
```

$status is an array containing several values i.e `$status['username'] = 'admin'`

The AJAX datatype is set to 'JSON' but I am not using `echo json_encode($status);` in my PHP but everything is still working and my $status array is processed by jQuery upon AJAX success. Why is this? I thought json_encode would be required but it seems it isn't.

Comment: Such a mystery. Not encoded array and without echo, are you sure everything works?

Comment: Yea it definitely works, I can get any of the values in $status to pop up in an alert message in jQuery.

Comment: Without the context 'where' the output is actually echoed/output this will remain a mystery and we can only guess

Comment: always use `json_encode` when trying to parse it with javascript

Comment: It would also help if you show us the array and function used to return `$status`

Answer (score 0):

json_encode  use but out of this function that you see the

```
  return $status;
```

on it  for understand it  you can  see developer tools in browser then find ajax request, see content response  . for find json_encode search for location of calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I had made a daft mistake, my function was indeed returning $status, but it was returning it to another function which performed the json_encode. Mystery solved :) Thanks.